# Voice To Text in PHP

Tags: php, voice-recording

Is it possible to convert voice mail into text using PHP? Is there any 3rd party voice to text converting software works well with PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not PHP, but you could use this as a open-source backend and make the necessary calls from PHP to system (exec, system etc.):
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

You can also check this tutorial (although commercial probably):
https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/php/laravel

Where the voicemail to text function relies on the Transcription Resource of the API.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/transcription